# Peer to Peer Connection using WAN & IP

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming, p2p

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an android peer to peer without using intermediate server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298047/how-to-make-an-android-peer-to-peer-without-using-intermediate-server)

I have a WAN address 209.179.xx.xx and the Ip on my Machine is 192.168.x.x 
can i ascess my machine remotely through Internet.
is it possible to make peer to peer connection using this Information.
I am working on Android.

Comment: u can do peer to peer connection for sending msg,using this http://code.google.com/p/sip2peer/ and for more information about this have a look at this issue carefully
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298047/how-to-make-an-android-peer-to-peer-without-using-intermediate-server Best Of Luck Aamirkhan I.

Answer (score 0):

For any two machine to communicate peer to peer, both should be able to [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) each other to make sure they are reachable. Your WAN should have a firewall which is restrict/control any incoming and outgoing connection. For the machine within WAN to be available on internet, your System admin needs to do some settings on firewall.

Comment: It's entirely possible for ping to be blocked while normal traffic gets through.